# CakePhP: How to define the base Url for a controller

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have an admin app in cakephp and inside this app I'm writing a controller: `ProductController.php`.

I want this controller to answer `mysite.com/adm/product/`  and after `product/` I want it to be my actions. Eg.: `product/report` I want it to call the report action of the controller.

I've been googling but so far I didn't find the answer. Maybe i'm not looking with the right tems. Anyway, could you help me please?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Cakephp 2.x` the you need to add a route to your `routes.php` file under `app/Config/routes.php`

Something along the lines of

```
Router::connect('/adm/*', array(
    'controller' => 'product',
));
```